# How to filter records that are within a given week

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have lesson records, each has a date
scheduled, I want to create a filter from a date, returns the lessons of that week, if date none return lessons of current week

I had some ideas and started writing something but I don't know how to finish

```py
class LessonWeeklyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    date = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='start_date', method='filter_weekly')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Lesson
        fields = [
            'date',
        ]

    def filter_weekly(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value == None:
            today = datetime.now().date()
            dt = datetime.strptime(day, '%d/%b/%Y')
            start = dt - timedelta(days=dt.weekday())
            end = start + timedelta(days=6)
```

EDIT: 
I try this, but doesn't work

```py
class LessonWeeklyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    date = filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name='start_date', method='filter_weekly')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Lesson
        fields = [
            'date',
        ]

    def filter_weekly(self, queryset, name, value):
        week = value.isocalendar()[1]
        return queryset.filter(start_date.isocalendar()[1] = week
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter qs by `date__week`.

`isocalendar()` method returns a tuple containing the number of week

```
class LessonWeeklyFilter(FilterSet):
    date_week = filters.DateFilter(field_name='date', method='filter_weekly', label="Lessons by week") # filter_name='date' change to your field name

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson # your model
        fields = ('date', ) # your model field 


    def filter_weekly(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value is None: # by the way not sure that its work, can't check now
            value = datetime.today().isocalendar()[1]
        else:
            value = value.isocalendar()[1]
        return queryset.filter(date__week=value)
```

works by `/api/lessons/?date_week=2019-08-27`

Comment: Thanks for answer bro, i receive this error Cannot resolve keyword 'date' into field. Choices are: ....

Comment: Oh, sure! I forgot about `class Meta:`. I fix my answer

Comment: return queryset.filter(date__week=value) is that right? i changed by date_weak and expected string or bytes-like objec

Comment: Sorry bro now I understand what you mean, its works thanks

Comment: I am glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the builtin datetime package. It supports the subtract operator for easily finding time deltas.

A simple example would be:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime(2019, 01, 01)
b = datetime(2019, 01, 10)
time_delta = b - a
if time_delta.days >= 7:
    # ** Logic goes here **
    print(time_delta)
```

output: datetime.delta(days=9)

So you can easily compare two dates with a simple subtraction and then referencing its days attribute.

Comment: Thanks for tip, i will try use this